# Combine form input value with selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to combine values from option and input fields in realtime by using jQuery.

```
<input name="recipe" id="recipe" value="tablespoons" />
<select id="spoon_value" name="spoon_value">
<option value="1" selected="">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Maybe something like this would work, but I'm getting error.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

```
$('select#spoon_value').each(function(i) {
$(select[name=spoon_value] option[value=" + this.data.spoon_value + "]").html() + this.data.recipe);
```

The output I want is 2tablespoons or 3tablespoons and so on.

Comment: your posted code has syntax error

Comment: Yes it has, that's why I'm here. @Nicholas I'm phping since past 20 hours. I can't even type well :D

Comment: You know, stackoverflow is not a debugging plateform... If you are unable to fix such kind of syntax error, then GL!

Comment: I think I should've posted it In code review section. Pardon me.

Comment: I haven't used [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but I'm fairly sure it's more for improving *working* code, not so much debugging your jquery selectors :). Just based on reading through the first couple of questions I saw there.

Comment: If that is so, I'm very sorry. No place for newbies in this world: http://i.imgur.com/4RPYlds.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function _(x){
            return document.getElementById(x);
        }
        function update() {
            var tbsVal = _("spoon_value").value;
            var output = tbsVal + " tablespoons";
            _("realtimeTbsVal").innerHTML = output;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="yourFileName" method="post">
        <select id="spoon_value" name="spoon_value" onblur="update()">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <div id="realtimeTbsVal">yo</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know jQuery was requested, but pure javascript can accomplish the same thing more efficiently.

Comment: If you want to keep the input for the tablespoons value just create a new javascript variable and concatenate them similar to above.

Comment: Tested it. It works. But it requires a click in body after changing option. Check it out here: http://jsbin.com/atUluTOP/1/ I think thats the difference between simple javascript and jQuery :D

Comment: @Waqas Did you want the value to update as soon as the new values are selected?

Comment: Yes, that what I wanted. Although I've achieved it in jQuery. But if its possible in simple javascript I'd like to see it :)

Comment: var output = tbsVal + " " + old; (if you want a space between the number and text)

Comment: Thanks, I updated it. Hope that it will help someone else in future.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing quotes around your selector inside your `each` function -- you also have an `each` function targeting an ID, which is bad because it most likely means you're repeating ID's. Here's a syntax correct version of your code:

```
$('select#spoon_value').each(function(i) {
    var someData = $("select[name=spoon_value] option[value=" + this.data.spoon_value + "]").html() + this.data.recipe;
});
```

Comment: Just tested it, Its not working either. I think I'd give a try to this method http://jsbin.com/onosex/107/edit But it removes the value upon changing options

Comment: Well the code above actually does do anything...it just creates a variable, did you do anything with said variable?

Comment: Yes my frield, I added  `$('#recipe').val('someData');` and  `$('[name=recipe]').val(someData);at` the end.

Comment: Try `$('#recipe').val(someData);` -- dont quote variables

Comment: This is awful that I failed to get the output with this function. Although there are no errors in console. `jQuery('select#spoon_value').change(function($) { var someData = $("select[name=spoon_value] option[value=" + this.data.spoon_value + "]").html() + this.data.recipe; jQuery('input#recipe').val(someData); });` Anyway I've made it working by storing the older value into variable and then combining both at the end of function `jQuery('input#recipe').val(option + old);` Thank for your help and time.